# Records cannot be deleted with this form access error

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have made a search box in Access that will set the Access form's recordset to ADO recordset once the result is found.

The code is

```
rs.Open "select * from main where Name= '" & Me.txtSearch.Value & "';", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
Set Me.Recordset = rs
```

This lets me find the records much faster than default Access `ctrl+f` method which is slower with linked tables.

However, it looks like I cannot delete the records that were found using the search field that I made.

If i try to delete it, I get:

> Records cannot be deleted with this form access

at the bottom of the form.

Is there a way to have deletable ADO record bound to Access form?

Comment: Check the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/open-method-ado-recordset?view=sql-server-2017), especially if you have undesired behavior and/or errors.  The default cursor type and lock type are `adOpenForwardOnly` and `adLockReadOnly`.  You need to set those values to something appropriate for updates and deletions.

Comment: Also, check in form properties if the form allows deletions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.allowdeletions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the ADO bound form was not editable is not because of cursor type or lock type  but because of cursor location. Adding

```
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
```

did the job for me.

Also in [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cb739128-11b3-4304-99d0-bfd6905c80de/is-this-documentation-right-client-side-cursors-recommended-for-ado-connections-to-sqlserver?forum=accessdev) discussion thread Dirk Goldgar writes:

> One possible consideration is that, if you're binding an Access form
> to an ADO recordset, I've found that using a server-side cursor makes
> the form read-only.

So far, I have not found any explanation on why this is the case. Please reply if anyone knows why server side cursor bound to Access form makes it uneditable.

EDIT 1:

Also Made Sure that you are using currentproject.connection and not an ADO connection string